# How change html View of ZF1 captcha

Tags: php, zend-framework

i am not using captcha in zend form i am directly writting zend captch code on controller. My code is:

**IndexController.php**

```
public function loginAction(){


        $this->view->assign('action',"/sabkuch/index/auth");
        $this->view->assign('user','username');
        $this->view->assign('passwd','Password');
        //$a=$this->_helper->Comman->textEmail("hi........","htm body.......","pkr","from@gm.com","xyz","xyz@gm.com");
        //echo $a; die;
        // Our form object...  

// And here's our captcha object...  
$captcha = new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha('captcha',  
        array('label' => 'Write the chars to the field',  
        'captcha' => array( // Here comes the magic...  
        // First the type... 

        'captcha' => 'Image',
        'useNumbers'  => true,
         'fontSize' => '22',
        'wordLen' => '4',
        'height' => '57',
        'width' => '235',
        // Captcha timeout, 5 mins  
        'timeout' => 300,  
        // What font to use...  
        'font' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/font/6.ttf',
        // Where to put the image  
        'imgDir' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/captcha/',  
        // URL to the images  
        // This was bogus, here's how it should be... Sorry again :S  
        'imgUrl' => 'http://localhost/sabkuch/public/captcha/',  
))); 

        $this->view->captcha = $captcha;

     }
```

**Login.phml**

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1"> 
<form class="form_align" name="login" method="post" action="<?php echo $this->escape($this->action);?>"> 
<tbody> 
<tr> 
<td align="left"><strong><?php echo $this->escape($this->user);?></strong></td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td align="left"><?php echo $this->formText('username', '', array(
                            'class' => 'textfield',
                            'alt'   => 'NOBLANK~loginEmail~DM~',
                            'size'  => '30',
                            ) 
                            ); ?>
</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td align="left"><strong><?php echo $this->escape($this->passwd);?></strong></td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td align="left"><?php echo $this->formPassword('passwd', '', array(
                            'class' => 'textfield',
                            'alt'   => 'NOBLANK~loginEmail~DM~',
                            'size'  => '30',
                            ) 
                            ); ?>
</td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td align="left"><strong>Set Captcha</strong></td> 
</tr>   


<tr> 
<td align="left"><?php                                                           
echo $this->captcha->render($this, null) ;
?>

</td></tr>
<tr> 
<td align="left" style="padding-top:5px">
<?php echo $this->formHidden('id', 'login'); ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">                  </td> 
    </tr> 
  </tbody> 
  </form>
</table>
```

captch code output is

```
<dd id="captcha-element">
<img width="235" height="57" alt="" src="http://localhost/sabkuch/public/captcha/770eec95f4b247754b4b6c30cd74a4a4.png" />
<input type="hidden" name="captcha[id]" value="770eec95f4b247754b4b6c30cd74a4a4" id="captcha-id" />
<input type="text" name="captcha[input]" id="captcha-input" value="" /></dd>
```

i need captcha html output as per my requirement like

```
 <tr><td> <dd id="captcha-element">
    <img width="235" height="57" alt="" src="http://localhost/sabkuch/public/captcha/770eec95f4b247754b4b6c30cd74a4a4.png" />
    <input type="hidden" name="captcha[id]" value="770eec95f4b247754b4b6c30cd74a4a4" id="captcha-id" />
</tr></td>

<tr><td>
    <input type="text" name="captcha[input]" id="captcha-input" value="" /></dd> 

</tr></td>
```

in zend form we cn add decoratro but i am directly using this captcha on controller How i change this ouput of html